# Shadow DOM: Elements attached to shadow DOM not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, shadow-dom, stenciljs

I'm trying to understand how radio buttons work within a shadow dom. I have a script tag where I'm attaching a shadow DOM to an element and then appending some radio buttons. My problem is that the radio buttons are not rendering.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Radio Buttons:</p>
<div id="containter">

</div>

<script>
    let shadowContainer = document.getElementById('containter');
    shadowContainer.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

    let input1 = document.createElement('input');
    input1.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    input1.setAttribute("id", "1");
    input1.setAttribute("name", "group");
    input1.setAttribute("value", "1");

    let input2 = document.createElement('input');
    input2.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    input2.setAttribute("id", "2");
    input2.setAttribute("name", "group");
    input2.setAttribute("value", "2");

    let input3 = document.createElement('input');
    input3.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    input3.setAttribute("id", "3");
    input3.setAttribute("name", "group");
    input3.setAttribute("value", "3");

    shadowContainer.appendChild(input1);
    shadowContainer.appendChild(input2);
    shadowContainer.appendChild(input3);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method, however the Examples of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow show that the `attachShadow()` method returns an element, and it is that element you append elements to.

Comment: Good catch. `let container = document.getElementById('containter');
    let shadowContainer = container.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});` is what I needed.

Comment: If you put that in an answer it's all yours.

Comment: Nah, that was just me pointing to documentation, :)

Comment: A true gentleman.

Comment: Lol should I delete my answer that I was writing when he wrote the comment?

Comment: @AdamH I wouldn't, since you appear to be familiar with the methodology, explained the issue, and offered a runnable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you aren't adding the elements to the shadowDom, you are adding them to the div. Simply store the return value from `.attachShadow` and append to that. Here is your example doing just that.

```js
let shadowContainer = document.getElementById('containter');
// store the reference
let container = shadowContainer.attachShadow({
  mode: 'open'
});

let input1 = document.createElement('input');
input1.setAttribute("type", "radio");
input1.setAttribute("id", "1");
input1.setAttribute("name", "group");
input1.setAttribute("value", "1");

let input2 = document.createElement('input');
input2.setAttribute("type", "radio");
input2.setAttribute("id", "2");
input2.setAttribute("name", "group");
input2.setAttribute("value", "2");

let input3 = document.createElement('input');
input3.setAttribute("type", "radio");
input3.setAttribute("id", "3");
input3.setAttribute("name", "group");
input3.setAttribute("value", "3");

// append to the reference 
container.appendChild(input1);
container.appendChild(input2);
container.appendChild(input3);
```

```html
<p>Radio Buttons:</p>
<div id="containter">

</div>
```

Comment: Mate, you are a life saver. The whole day I am looking for the "bug". Thanks!